# How do I include an onCLick inside a for loop in React?

Tags: json, for-loop, reactjs, webpack

I'll try my hardest to keep this as concise as possible.

I want to be able to delete items from my json data state(library) but at the moment i can't even get a simple console.log to fire when the "Delete" button is clicked.

Every thing displays perfectly on load.
I get an error when I write in the `onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this)}` event for the `"Delete"` button.

Parent component:

```
   constructor(){

  super();
  this.state = {
    test: "SiteFront State",
    library : {
      "copy" : {
        "name" : "Copy",
        "input" :  "CMD + C",
        "os" : "All"
      },
      "paste" : {
        "name" : "paste",
        "input" :  "CMD + V",
        "os" : "All"
      }
    },
    libraryKeys:null
  };
};
```

Child Component:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.SetUpItemsHandler();
};

componentWillReceiveProps(){
  this.SetUpItemsHandler();
}

deleteClickHandler(e){
  console.log("delete Button Clicked");
};

SetUpItemsHandler(){
  var libraryKeys = Object.keys(this.props.library);
  document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML = "";
  for(var i = 0;i < libraryKeys.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML += "<li key={i}>"+
      "<h2>Name: "+ this.props.library[libraryKeys[i]].name +"</h1>"+
      "<button onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this ,i)}>Delete</button>"
    "</li>";
};
};
```

`The onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this)}` event fires an error in the console:

> (index):16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of
>   undefined(…)

Am I including the key value correctly? What am I missing? 
I have used .map functions with arrays but am not sure the ideal way to do it with json key objects so I've tried to use a for loop instead. Is this wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you,
Moe

EDIT: 
Inside my render function I have tried to include but it's not taking, nothing displays without any errors in the console:

```
  render(){

    var listItems = function(){
      var libraryKeys = Object.keys(this.props.library);
      document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML = "";
      for(var i = 0;i < libraryKeys.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML += "<li key={i}>"+
        "<h2>Name: "+ this.props.library[libraryKeys[i]].name +"</h1>"+
        "<button onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this)}>Delete</button>"+
        "</li>"
      };
  };

    return(
      <div>
        Library Here<br/><br/>
        <div id="library">
          <ul id="libraryInner">
            {listItems}
          </ul>
        </div>

      <AddItemForm
        inputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        nameInputUpdateHandler={this.props.nameInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        inputInputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        osInputUpdateHandler={this.props.osInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        addItemHandler={this.props.addItemHandler.bind(this)}
      />

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: you are getting error because you manipulating direct HTML, and it doesn't know bind, to use bind the html should be generated using react html elements.  why didn't you render the html using render method ?

Comment: I have edited the post with an update where I included function inside the render function. It didn't take. Nothing displays without any console errors.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your `SetUpItemsHandler()` Also in your edit I see that you have created a function listItems but you are not calling it as a function or returning anything from it.

```
    SetUpItemsHandler = () =>{
      var libraryKeys = Object.keys(this.props.library);
       document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML = "";
       for(var i = 0;i < libraryKeys.length;i++){
           document.getElementById("libraryInner").innerHTML += "<li key={i}>"+
       "<h2>Name: "+ this.props.library[libraryKeys[i]].name +"</h1>"+
      "<button onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this ,i)}>Delete</button>"
    "</li>";
     }
    };
```

**Making use of map**

```
SetUpItemsHandler = () =>{

    Object.keys(this.props.library).map(function(keyValue, index){
      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <h2>Name: {this.props.library[keyValue].name}</h2>
          <button onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this, i)}>Delete</button>
        </li>
      )
    }.bind(this))
};
```

You can call this function in your render as

```
render(){

    return(
      <div>
        Library Here<br/><br/>
        <div id="library">
          <ul id="libraryInner">
            {this.SetUpItemsHandler()}
          </ul>
        </div>

      <AddItemForm
        inputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        nameInputUpdateHandler={this.props.nameInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        inputInputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        osInputUpdateHandler={this.props.osInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
        addItemHandler={this.props.addItemHandler.bind(this)}
      />

      </div>
    );
  }
```

**P.S.** the above code is not tested, you will have to provide a object structure of `this.props.library` for me to be sure and that the above code is based on how you have implemented the for loop.

Comment: I tried to include your method in my build. No luck unfortunately. It fires an error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./Library.js"(…)

Comment: is Library.js your file name. If yes then this error results because of a syntax error in the file and not otherwise. If you are using webpack then while building it whill show you the exact place where the syntax error points to

Answer (score 1):

replace your render method with this.

```
    render(){
      return(
          <div>
            Library Here<br/><br/>
            <div id="library">
              <ul id="libraryInner">
                {(()=>{
                 let listItems = [];
                 for(var i = 0;i < Object.keys(this.props.library);i++){
                    listItems.push(<li key={i}>
                                      <h2>Name:{this.props.library[libraryKeys[i]].name} </h2>
                                      <button onClick={this.deleteClickHandler.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
                                   </li>);
                  }
                  return  listItems;    
                })()}
              </ul>
            </div>

          <AddItemForm
            inputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
            nameInputUpdateHandler={this.props.nameInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
            inputInputUpdateHandler={this.props.inputInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
            osInputUpdateHandler={this.props.osInputUpdateHandler.bind(this)}
            addItemHandler={this.props.addItemHandler.bind(this)}
          />

          </div>
        );
      }
```